# Multi module web application maven architecture with Spring boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I'm building a web application that contains several modules and I want to split each of these modules to a single project. This is the first time I'm trying to do such thing, I used to make the application in one project and I don't want to start the development with a wrong architecture.
What I want to do:

```
--Maven parent project
    -- main app: Spring boot, Database connection, authentication, user management.
    -- Module 1,2 .. n: modules, repositories, controllers
```

So the idea is splitting the project by functionality on the use case perspective. The question is: can this architecture work without problems and how can I configure it with maven?

Comment: You may need to refer this first https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

1) have a parent pom that holds it all together, this is your parent that has a parent of spring-boot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>boot-library</module>
        <module>boot-web</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

2) have as many library modules as you wish:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <artifactId>boot-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>boot-library</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

3) Then have as many spring boot modules as you wish that will pull in the required libraries from the same project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>boot-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>boot-web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.essexboy</groupId>
            <artifactId>boot-library</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
        <!-- tag::tests[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::tests[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```